# Android login with Arabic values failed

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, httpurlconnection

I wrote this application that takes the username and password entered by a user and checks if the user exists. (login)
It works when I insert English values but when I insert Arabic values it fails. Can someone help me please?

This is the code for the login:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText userName , password;
String res = "toomy";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
}

public void login(View view) {
    String name = userName.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();
    String type="login";

    BackgroundTask background= new BackgroundTask(this);
    background.execute(type, name, pass).toString();
}

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog ;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login information...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String login_url="http://192.168.173.1/loginf.php";
        String method= params[0];
        if(method.equals("login")){
            String name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            try {

                URL url= new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                 String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response= "";
                String line= "";
                while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                res = response;
                Log.d("hgjh",res);
                return res;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//end of if
        return null;
    }//end of method doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Login success")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "login faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}//end of class BackgroundTask
```

}

And this is the PHP code:

```html
<?php
require"conn.php";
$result='';
$user_name=$_POST['name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql_query="select name FROM school where name like '$user_name' and password like '$password';";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
  $result="Login success";
  echo "Login success";
  }
  else{
  $result="login failed";
  echo"login failed";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @toomy - dump the $sql_query so you can test the query directly on mysql or phpMyAdmin or whatever. Possibly you have some underlying issue, like the collation in use for the table. I'd check that first if it's working for other languages.

Comment: i also changed the collation to  cp1256_general_ci but also login faild

Comment: I tested values and succeed in phpMyAdmin but it faild in php